# Ghost tab at the end of navbar page within shiny context

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

As shown in the below image, I have a problem with a ghost tab that appears at the end of my navbar page. 
The ghost tab disappears when the code below at the end of ui is deleted. The code is related to the loading sign. How can I fix this?

```
hidden(
div(
  id = "app-content"
  #p("")
)
```

)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by moving the mentioned code to right after ui <- fluidPage(.

```
    ui <- fluidPage(
  hidden(
    div(
      id = "app-content"
      #p("")
    )
  ),
```